# Lazy loading with common provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have implemented lazy loading pattern on `ionic 3` project.It works awesomely.
I have one question though.Let's say I need to implement native `StatusBar` features on the app.Hence I have to implement it on each page differently, I have put that on `app.module.ts` as shown below.

```
providers: [
    StatusBar,
]
```

Is this good approach or Do I need to inject `StatusBar` as a `provider` on each component's module? To me, it seems redundant work.But what is the best way of doing it and why's that?

Comment: If the module not is lazy loading you can to register the provider an many modules  that the root injector charges the provider once, If the module is lazy loading the provider is register in child injector. When the app start the root injector does not permit add new provider

Comment: Sorry I didn't get exactly what you said.Can you put more info about it? I have implemented lazy loading on my project.So all the components are supporting lazy loading now. @alehn96

Comment: Since it's just a provider (and not an entire module), you can just add it to the providers array of the `app.module.ts` file. That's the recommended way to use most of the cordova plugins (since they're not modules, just _providers_).

Comment: I think your comment is the best suit for the `Ionic context`.Can you put that as an answer? Thanks.@sebaferreras

Comment: Hope you saw my feedback above no? @sebaferreras

Comment: Oh, sorry. just saw the comment... It's done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though @SrAxi's answer is perfect, when using Cordova plugins in Ionic and since the plugins are just *used as providers* (and not entire modules), you can just add it to the providers array of the `app.module.ts` file and everything should work fine.

That's the recommended way to use most of the cordova plugins (since they're not modules, just providers)

Comment: Thanks! :D But, I didn't know `StatusBar` was a Cordova plugin.. :(  Anyways, nice to know! Thanks! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can add `StatusBar` to your AppModule's `providers` if you want that service to be used globally. But it may give you some issues with instances if `StatusBar` is not only a `Service`. (I had some issues with this approach).

Immagine that you had, `I18nModule` (for translations), that contains its services. By adding `I18nModule` to AppModule's `imports`, I'll have several instances of the services within `I18nModule`.

A solution for that would be to use `forRoot()`:

```
export class I18nModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: I18nModule,
            providers: [I18nService, MyService1, MyService2]
        };
    }
}
```

And then in `AppModule`:

```
imports: [
   I18nModule.forRoot(),
]
```

With `forRoot()` we will instance `I18nModule` *(and its services, returning to your question)* as a **singleton**.

**Summing up:**

It's ok if it's just a service, but if its a service that is part of a module you have to take care of not instancing 2 times the same service and then you'll spend hours trying to understand why a *'working'* service is not doing its job.

**Update:**

Angular was intended to be modular, therefore, it's encouraged to created modules for each context, example:

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,

        CoreModule,
        LayoutModule,
        I18nModule.forRoot(),
        BarHandlingModule, // Example
        InventedModule  // Example too
    ],
```

Meaning that after reading Angular's docs, you should be creating a module for your Core functionality, another for your User's context, another for Orders, another for Clients, etc. If you know what I mean.

So, instead of adding services to your `AppModule`, try creating a module for each major context in your app, and add those to your `imports` in `AppModule`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation about how to handle it with Angular.But I would like to know how to handle it with Ionic.Especially `StatuBar` is a Cordova plugin.

Comment: @Sampath Oh man! Sorry! Didn't know `StatusBar` was a Cordova plugin! :S